# Como fazer notificação de "nova" igual do Gmail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.
Estou procurando como fazer uma notificação de "nova" igual do Gmail:

[image: Gmail]

Ou seja, quando houver um novo item na lista aparecer a tag "nova" e somente sumir depois que a pessoa visualizar.

Pelo que parece o gmail **não** faz uma requisição `ajax`, não tenho certeza.
Acredito que seja alguma coisa relacionada a Javascript.

Acredito que seja algum tipo de plugin tipo "viewport" ou seja, que quando o usuario visualiza, ele mostra a tag. Mas não sei exatamente.

Alguem sabe como fazer um efeito parecido?

Comment: Seja mais claro, o que deseja saber a lógica ou como implementar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questão interessante. Fiz um exemplo usando jQuery e Javascript.

O primeiro passo é uma função que percorre itens que são potencialmente novos e adiciona o marcador quando necessário:

```js
//marca itens novos
function highlightItems() {
    console.log('--- highlightItems ---');
    //percorre todos os itens
    $('.item-novo').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
        //verifica se o item é recente
        var adicionado = $(this).data('adicionado');
        if (!adicionado || adicionado > updateTimestamp) {
            //cria marcador
            var marcador = $('<span class="new">novo!</span>');
            //adiciona ao item
            $(this).append(marcador);
            //agenda desaparecimento
            marcador.delay(3000).fadeOut(1500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
            //atualizada momento em que foi exibido para não exibir depois
            $(this).data('adicionado', updateTimestamp);
        }
    });
    updateTimestamp = Date.now();
}
```

Se os itens são adicionados via Ajax, eles devem ser marcados com a classe CSS `item-novo`, como em `<div class="item">...</div>`.

Ainda no exemplo, os itens que vem do servidor devem vir com um atributo `data-adicionado`, cujo valor deve ser um número inteiro (*timestamp* ) representando a data do item.

A variável `updateTimestamp` deve conter a data em que o servidor retornou dados para o usuário pela última vez.

Além disso, é possível adicionar eventos para detectar quando usuário está olhando sua página. O evento `focus` da janela (`window)` será disparado quando o usuário clicar em qualquer parte da janela ou frame. Também é possível verificar se o usuário está com o mouse sobre a janela por algum tempo, usando o evento `mousemove` e um *timer*.

Juntando tudo isso fiz os seguintes manipuladores de eventos:

```
//lembra se a janela recebeu o foco
var janelaTemFoco = false;

//timer para atualizar a página
var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
    //executa ação apenas se o usuário estiver vendo a janela
    if (janelaTemFoco) {
        highlightItems();
    }
}, 1000);

//eventos de foco da janela
$(window).focus(function() {
    console.log('--- focus ---');
    janelaTemFoco = true;
    highlightItems();
});
$(window).blur(function() {
    console.log('--- blur ---');
    janelaTemFoco = false;
});
//se o usuário parar o mouse, também mostra
var mouseInterval = 0;
$(window).mousemove(function() {
    console.log('--- mousemove ---');
    if (mouseInterval == 0) {
        clearInterval(mouseInterval);
        mouseInterval = setTimeout(highlightItems, 1000);
    }
});
$(window).mouseout(function() {
    console.log('--- mouseout ---');
    clearInterval(mouseInterval);
    mouseInterval = 0;
});
```

O *timer* presente no evento, roda a cada segundo e, se o foco estiver na janela, ele realça os itens novos.

O primeiro evento (`focus`) também realça os itens sempre que o usuário volta com o foco para a janela. Já o evento  `blur` evita que os itens sejam realçados quando o usuário vai para outra janela.

Por último, os eventos `mousemove` e `mouseout` identificam se o usuário está com o mouse por pelo menos um segundo sobre a janela e então realça os itens. Caso contrário, por exemplo, se o usuário apenas passou o mouse rapidamente sobre a janela, ele não faz nada.

Fiz um teste funcional, porém sem a parte de atualizar do servidor. Os itens são gerados aleatoriamente a cada 5 segundos.

### [Demo no Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/GgeS7/3/)

Comment: Cara, fantástico!! Eu tava fazendo umas coisas no fiddle também porque acho que esse lance do gmail é bem interessante...Acho que sua resposta é a melhor. Ainda estou tentando entender completamente

Answer (score 0):

Todas as mensagens possuem um `status`, e por ele é controlada a forma de exibição das mensagens (um simples replace de classes CSS). No caso das requisições ajax, sim, elas existem, mas são executadas periodicamente. O Gmail baseia-se bastante em `LocalStorage` para garantir performance.

Se você tem um `JSON` para armazenar suas mensagens:

```
{
    id : 123456789456,
    subject : "Teste"
    status : 1 // Nova mensagem
} (...)
```

É simples aplicar esse conceito ao baseá-lo em comunicação periódica com o servidor, usando por exemplo o padrão loop que não encavala requests:

```
function sync() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Faz operações de sincronização

        if (finished) // Se a operação atual terminou
            sync(); // Re-executa a função
    }, 30000); // Sincroniza a cada 30 s
}
```